# Permutator not producing lexicographic output

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking

I was working on problem 24 on project euler, after a couple of days researching and thouroughly understanding what backtracking is and how to implement it, I finally got my permutator to work,  here it is:

```
//Lexicographic Permutations, Project Euler Problem 24
/*The lexicographic permutations of 0, 1 and 2 are:
012   021   102   120   201   210
What is the millionth lexicographic permutation of the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9? */

#include <stdio.h>
#define TARGET 1000000 

int iteration=0;

int permute(char*,int,int);
int swap(int,int);
char digits[10]="0123456789";


int main(){
    permute(digits,0,9);
}

int permute(char*digits,int start, int end){
//  printf("permute(%s, %d, %d)\n",digits,start,end);
    if (start==end){
        iteration++;
//  if ((iteration==TARGET) printf ("iteration %d: %s\n",iteration, digits);
    }else

        for (int i=start ; i<=end ; i++){
            swap (start, i);
            permute (digits, start+1, end);
            swap (start, i);
        }
    return 0;
}

int swap(int a,int b){
//  printf("swap(%d,%d)\n",a,b);
    int temp;
    temp=digits[a];
    digits[a]=digits[b];
    digits[b]=temp;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the correct answer to the problem should be 2783915460 which in my case is located on iteration 998580...
Heres some sample output:

```
...
2783915604 found at iteration:998575
2783915640 found at iteration:998576
2783915064 found at iteration:998577
2783915046 found at iteration:998578
2783915406 found at iteration:998579
2783915460 found at iteration:998580
....
```

I've tried to understand the logic of the backtracking call by printing the parameters of each call, here's an excerpt:

```
permute(0123746589, 7, 9)
permute(0123746589, 8, 9)
permute(0123746589, 9, 9)
permute(0123746598, 9, 9)
permute(0123746859, 8, 9)
permute(0123746859, 9, 9)
permute(0123746895, 9, 9)
permute(0123746985, 8, 9)
permute(0123746985, 9, 9)
permute(0123746958, 9, 9)
```

I just can't figure out why the output is not being produced in lexicographic order? anyone that can perhaps explain and advice on how to correct it, I mean I have the solution but I really want to be able to make my program work as intended.

P.S. I've heard that when it comes to recursive backtracking programmers usually just say: "It doesn't work but I don't know why" or "it works but I don't know why"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it now, had to refactor the whole thing, I went for a more straightforward approach, after a while I was having a hard time understanding the mechanics myself which is always a symptom of bad coding. Thanks anyway, heres the code for the lexicographic output:

```
//Lexicographic Permutations, Project Euler Problem 24
#include <stdio.h>
#define TARGET 1000000 

int iteration=0;

int permute(char*,int);
int swap(int,int);
int indent(int);

char digits[10]="0123456789";
int available[10]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

int main(){
    char selected[10]={0};
    permute(selected,0);
}

int permute(char selectedSoFar[],int position){
//  indent(position);
//  printf("permute(%s, %d)\n",selectedSoFar,position);

    if (position==10){
        iteration++;
        if(iteration==TARGET) printf ("iteration %3d: %s\n",iteration, selectedSoFar);

    }else{
        for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
            if (available[i]==1){
                available[i]=0;
                selectedSoFar[position]=i+'0';
                permute(selectedSoFar,position+1);
                selectedSoFar[position]='\0';
                available[i]=1;
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}

int indent(int level){
    while (level>0){
        printf("  ");
        level--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's a peek of the mechanics behind it ( tried to make it clearer )

```
permute(, 0)
  permute(0, 1)
    permute(01, 2)
      permute(012, 3)
        permute(0123, 4)
          permute(01234, 5)
            permute(012345, 6)
              permute(0123456, 7)
                permute(01234567, 8)
                  permute(012345678, 9)
                    permute(0123456789, 10)
iteration   1: 0123456789
                  permute(012345679, 9)
                    permute(0123456798, 10)
iteration   2: 0123456798
                permute(01234568, 8)
                  permute(012345687, 9)
                    permute(0123456879, 10)
iteration   3: 0123456879
                  permute(012345689, 9)
```